# not able to show messagebox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I am making a quiz game, after every question you click submit and if the answer is correct you get a point, then you click next and you go to the next question. But when you click next on the last question, the code is supposed to display a message saying "Thanks For Playing!" "Your Score Is :" {Your Score}, but this isn't happening.

```
import random
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()

score = IntVar()

Score = Label(root,text = "SCORE:")
Score.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Scorenum = Label(root,textvariable = score)
Scorenum.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
questionslist = ["Who was the first president of the U.S.?","Which person had the highest IQ?","Who was the first person on the moon?"]
class question():
    def __init__(self, question, answer, options, answer_index):
        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.question = Label(self.frame,text = question)
        self.answer = answer 
        self.tracker = IntVar()
        self.option_list = []
        s = 0
        for loop1 in options:
            options = Radiobutton(self.frame,text = loop1,variable = self.tracker,value = s)
            s = s + 1
            self.option_list.append(options)
        self.answer_index = answer_index
    def show_question(self):
        x = 2
        self.question.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        for loop2 in self.option_list:
            loop2.grid(row = x, column = 0,sticky = W)
            x = x + 1
    def hide_question(self):
        self.frame.grid_forget()
def Next():
    global y
    question_list[y].hide_question()
    y = y + 1
    if y > 5:
        messagebox.showinfo("Thanks For Playing!", "Your Score Was:", score)
    question_list[y].show_question()
Next = Button(root,text = "Next",fg = "blue",command = Next)
Next.grid(row = 2, column = 1,sticky = W)

def Submit():
    global y
    if question_list[y].tracker.get() == question_list[y].answer_index:
        score.set(score.get() + 1)
        messagebox.showinfo("WOW!", "Thats Correct!")
        
Submit = Button(root,text = "Submit",fg = "red", command = Submit)
Submit.grid(row = 2, column = 0,sticky = W)
    

    
question1 = question("Who was the first president of the U.S.?", "George Washington", ["Bill Clinton", "George Washington", "Abraham Lincoln", "Joe Biden"], 1)
question2 = question("Who Made The Theory Of Relativity", "Shravan", ["Steven Hawking", "Albert Einstien", "Shravan", "Iisac Newton"], 2)
question3 = question("Who made the law of attraction", "Iisac Newton", ["Albert Einstien", "Iisac Newton", "Nicola Tesla", "Thomas Eddison"], 1)
question4 = question("Why was 6 afraid of 7", "Because 7 8 9", ["It wasn't", "This is a dumb question", "Because 7 8 9", "becaause 7 is bigger than 6"], 2)
question4 = question("Why was 6 afraid of 7", "Because 7 8 9", ["It wasn't", "This is a dumb question", "Because 7 8 9", "becaause 7 is bigger than 6"], 2)
question5 = question("Did you enjoy this test?", "Yes", ["Yes","No"],0)
question_list = [question1,question2,question3,question4,question5]
y = 0
question_list[y].show_question()
```

I would appreciate a fixed code and an explanation - Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a duplicate `question4` fyi however, I believe the `messagebox` only takes the title and one option for message so if you notice your other `messagebox` "WOW!" ends up being your title and 'That's correct!" ends up being the message. So if you don't mind that "Thanks For Playing! Your score was" would end up being your title(all in the same "") then all you would have to do is add something like this right above that `messagebox` call `final_score = score.get()` and then pass `final_score` in place of the message argument (so where you have `score` after the message)

Comment: Thankyou, I'm aware of how messagebox works, but my original question was the messagebox isn't displaying. At the end when I click next on the last question, there is no popup saying "Your Score Is: {}", I get the error

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/vijay/Documents/Lesson 3 Tkinter(FRAMES).py", line 261, in Next
    question_list[y].show_question()
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

So the reason you get that error is because there are no conditions to check if the next question should be shown. You have 5 elements in the list but when you evaluate the y it will go from 0-4 not 1-5.  So I added statements to check if it should continue in the  list.  However, what I was trying to point out to you in the comment is that you can't pass 3 arguments to your `messagebox` so even if your list index out of range error didn't exist your `messagebox` will still give you an error.  So I added changes to that also.  You have to check the value of y before passing it to your `messagebox` and then use an f string to prevent the `messagebox` error that you didn't see yet. I threw in the `print(y)` so you can see the value. I also added the `root.mainloop()` so it works outside of the python IDLE I hope this helps.

```
import random
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()

score = IntVar()

Score = Label(root,text = "SCORE:")
Score.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Scorenum = Label(root,textvariable = score)
Scorenum.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
#questionslist = ["Who was the first president of the U.S.?","Which person had the highest IQ?","Who was the first person on the moon?"]
class question():
    def __init__(self, question, answer, options, answer_index):
        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.question = Label(self.frame,text = question)
        self.answer = answer 
        self.tracker = IntVar()
        self.option_list = []
        s = 0
        for loop1 in options:
            options = Radiobutton(self.frame,text = loop1,variable = self.tracker,value = s)
            s = s + 1
            self.option_list.append(options)
        self.answer_index = answer_index
    def show_question(self):
        x = 2
        self.question.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        for loop2 in self.option_list:
            loop2.grid(row = x, column = 0,sticky = W)
            x = x + 1
    def hide_question(self):
        self.frame.grid_forget()
def Next():
    global y
    if y < 4:
        print(y)
        question_list[y].hide_question()
        y = y + 1
        question_list[y].show_question()
    elif y >= 4:
        final_score = score.get()
        messagebox.showinfo("Thanks For Playing!", f"Your Score Was:{final_score}")
    else:
        pass

Next = Button(root,text = "Next",fg = "blue",command = Next)
Next.grid(row = 2, column = 1,sticky = W)

def Submit():
    global y
    if question_list[y].tracker.get() == question_list[y].answer_index:
        score.set(score.get() + 1)
        messagebox.showinfo("WOW!", "Thats Correct!")
        
Submit = Button(root,text = "Submit",fg = "red", command = Submit)
Submit.grid(row = 2, column = 0,sticky = W)
    

    
question1 = question("Who was the first president of the U.S.?", "George Washington", ["Bill Clinton", "George Washington", "Abraham Lincoln", "Joe Biden"], 1)
question2 = question("Who Made The Theory Of Relativity", "Shravan", ["Steven Hawking", "Albert Einstien", "Shravan", "Iisac Newton"], 2)
question3 = question("Who made the law of attraction", "Iisac Newton", ["Albert Einstien", "Iisac Newton", "Nicola Tesla", "Thomas Eddison"], 1)
#question4 = question("Why was 6 afraid of 7", "Because 7 8 9", ["It wasn't", "This is a dumb question", "Because 7 8 9", "becaause 7 is bigger than 6"], 2)
question4 = question("Why was 6 afraid of 7", "Because 7 8 9", ["It wasn't", "This is a dumb question", "Because 7 8 9", "becaause 7 is bigger than 6"], 2)
question5 = question("Did you enjoy this test?", "Yes", ["Yes","No"],0)
question_list = [question1,question2,question3,question4,question5]
y = 0
question_list[y].show_question()


root.mainloop()
```